# API query using dateRangeInput in R

Tags: r, rest, shiny

I am trying to query a range of dates from an API in R/Shiny.  I use dateRangeInput to specify the range, and the API documentation specifies that the call is:

spuddate, Value should be in the RFC3339 format, Latest date that drilling commenced on the property. Example: spuddate=gt(2006-01-02T15:04:05Z) spuddate=le(2017-03).

How would I do this correctly?

I've tried several methods using anytime and rfc3339 but I keep getting various errors.  I suspect it has to be something around the way I structure the input call in server.

```
#UI - Obviously there are more but for sake of brevity here is the subset
sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               selectizeInput('stateSelect','STATE', choices= paste0(state.abb, sep=''), multiple=FALSE))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               selectizeInput('directionSelect','HOLE DIRECTION', choices= c('H','V','D','U'), multiple=FALSE))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               dateRangeInput("dateSelect", label = h3("Spud Date range")))
      ),
```

```
#Server Try So Far -- Obviously there are more but for sake of brevity here is the subset
observeEvent(input$select, {
      wellInfo <- GET("https://di-api.drillinginfo.com/v2/direct-access/producing-entities",
                      add_headers(c('X-API-KEY' = key, 'Authorization' = addToken, 'Accept' = 'text/xml')),
                      query=list(drilltype = dput(input$directionSelect), state = dput(input$stateSelect),
                                 spuddate = (rfc3339(anytime(input$dateSelect[1])),rfc3339(anytime(input$dateSelect[2]))),
                                 pagesize = 100000))
})
```

I just want to get the query to go off.  It works without the spuddate call (ie just the state and drilltype query).  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured out a brute force solution.

```
date1 <- paste('btw(',date(anytime(input$dateSelect[1])),
                     ',',date(anytime(input$dateSelect[2])),')', sep='')

      wellInfo <- GET("https://di-api.drillinginfo.com/v2/direct-access/producing-entities",
                      add_headers(c('X-API-KEY' = key, 'Authorization' = addToken, 'Accept' = 'text/xml')),
                      query=list(drilltype = dput(input$directionSelect), state = dput(input$stateSelect),
                                 spuddate = dput(date1),
                                 #spuddate <= (as.POSIXct(as.character(input$dateSelect2, format = '%Y-%m'))),
                                 pagesize = 100000))
```